# Should every function be declared on the $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was wondering what the best practice would be in regards to declaring functions on the `$scope` object. If i have a function that isn't used on the HTML page should it be declared on the `$scope`?

For example:

```
$scope.pageModel = { variables }

$scope.pageModel.btnSearchOnClick = function() {
       // some action
}

function randomFunction() {
       // some more actions
}
```

The `btnSearchOnClick()` function is used in the HTML, for example, here:

```
<button name = "btnSearch" ng-click = "pageModel.btnSearchOnClick" ... >
```

The `randomFunction()` function however may never be needed in the HTML that makes use of this controller so is it ok to declare it like I have above? Or should every function inside the controller be attached to the `$scope`?

Comment: Only attach to `$scope` what you're going to access from `$scope`.

Comment: i had experiences of variable not accessible everywhere without the scope, so you can do like that, but sometimes, even if you don't need it in the HTML, it will be usefull

Comment: I am paranoid so I put most things either in the scope or in a service object, which in the end will do the same. I am not sure it s best practice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have set it up is preferable to exposing everything on $scope, if you ask me.

I'm not sure there is a general consensus on this topic or a "*best practice*", so I would go with what you have.

Functions that do not need to be called from the $scope or the view, can generally be defined the way you've done it.

What I also like to do, is if a function gets really heavy that is exposed unto $scope - split it up into smaller, more to the point functions that do separate tasks.

The downside of not exposing these functions onto $scope is the lack of testability (one could argue that you don't care about the internal implementation in your unit tests however). A way around that is to define them on the Controller itself. As such:

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  $scope.exposed = function () {
    ctrl.internal();
  });

  ctrl.internal = function () {
    console.log('Internal function called from $scope');
  });
});
```

This way, in your unit tests - you could do something like this (bare in mind this is just a crude example):

```
describe('someCtrl', function () {
  var Subject, $scope;

  beforeEach(function () {
    // setup...

    inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();

      Subject = $controller('someCtrl', {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    });
  });


  context('$scope', function () {
    it('has an exposed function', function () {
      expect($scope).to.have.property('exposed').and.to.be.a('function');
    });
  });

  context('internals', function () {
    it('has an internal function', function () {
      expect(Subject).to.have.property('internal').and.to.be.a('function');
    });
  });

});
```